# Returning a variable - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to display information from an array

Here is my php code:

```
<?

include('class.prmessage.php');
$mess = new OMessaging(true);
$array = $mess->GetAllMesseges(0,9);
?>
```

and this is the function it calls:

```
    function GetAllMesseges($order = 0, $receiver = '', $sender = '')
{
    switch( $order )
    {
        case 0:
            $order = 'readed ASC';
        case 1:
            $order = 'readed DESC';
    }
    $where = '';
    if(strlen($receiver) > 0 && strlen($sender) > 0)
        $where = ' AND ';

    $where = ((strlen($receiver) > 0)?'receiver=' . $receiver:'') . $where . ((strlen($sender) > 0)?'sender=' . $sender:'');

    $result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$this->tblName." WHERE $where ORDER BY $order");

    if( !$result )
        return 1;
    echo $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $messege = '';
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $num ; $i++ )
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
        $messege[$i]['receiver'] = $row->receiver;
        $messege[$i]['sender'] = $row->sender;
        $messege[$i]['title'] = $row->title;
        $messege[$i]['body'] = $row->body;
        $messege[$i]['readed'] = $row->readed;  
        $messege[$i]['date'] = $row->date;
    }
    if( !is_array($messege) )
        return 2;
    return $messege;
```

i can access all the information i want to access, however when i declare  the array:

```
$array = $mess->GetAllMessages(0,9)
```

it outputs the array length on screen.

How can i stop this?

Comment: Get rid of the `echo` in the function...?!

Comment: `@mysql_query(` — Please do not use the error suppression operator to suppress error messages. And please don't use `mysql_*` functions either. They are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), no longer maintained and will be [removed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future.

Comment: Sidenote: You need breaks for your case(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
echo $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

To this:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

There are other problems you might want to fix in your code though. As [*Amal* points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344102/returning-a-variable-php#comment35748584_23344102), the `mysql` package is officially deprecated. From the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> **Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be 
>   removed in the  future. Instead, the [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)
>   extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide
>   and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

Also, your [`switch` statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) is broken. Without a `break` statement, the execution will 'fall through' to the next `case` label. For example:

```
$order = 0;
switch( $order )
{
    case 0:
        echo 'readed ASC <br>';
    case 1:
        echo 'readed DESC <br>';
}
```

Will print *both* lines:

```
readed ASC
readed DESC
```

So in your code, if `$order` is either `0` or `1`, it will be assigned a value of `'readed DESC'`. You can fix this with a simple [`break` statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php), like this:

```
switch( $order )
{
    case 0:
        $order = 'readed ASC';
        break;
    case 1:
        $order = 'readed DESC';
}
```